# Inserting "Entry" boxes based on user input in TKinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Newbie here, I am working on a small Python project and it requires to accept a numerical input from user and upon a button click it should insert that number of rows - entry boxes - for further input collection. Is it possible to do it in a loop and how? I tried it in a loop but is inserting only first row.

```
label_6.place(x=0,y=320) 
total_participants = tk.Entry(root, width="5", textvariable=StringVar())
total_participants.place(x=150,y=320)

def action():

    num_participants = int(total_participants.get())

    coordinate = 400

    first_name_label = Label(root, text="First Name",width=20,font=("bold", 11))
    first_name_label.place(x=0,y=coordinate)

    second_name_label = Label(root, text="Second Name",width=20,font=("bold", 11))
    second_name_label.place(x=150,y=coordinate)

    email_label = Label(root, text="Email ID",width=20,font=("bold", 11))
    email_label.place(x=300, y =coordinate )

    first_name = []
    second_name = []
    email_id = []

    for i in range(1, num_participants + 1):
         fn[i] = Entry(root, width="15").place(x=40,y=coordinate + 40)
         sn[i] = Entry(root, width="15").place(x=190,y=coordinate + 40)
         em[i] = Entry(root, width="40").place(x=340,y=coordinate + 40)

label_8 = Button(root, text="Participants Details",font=("bold", 13), command = participant_details)

label_8.place(x=30,y=360)
```

Comment: You need to update `coordinate` in each iteration.  Add something like `coordinate += 30` as the last line of for loop in `action()` (actually it should be `participant_details()`).  Also you should not chain the `.place()` function with the `Entry()`.  Separate the two functions into two statements.  And `fn[i]` should be `first_name.append(...)`, so for `sn[i]` and `em[i]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Entry widgets using a loop in Python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813735/multiple-entry-widgets-using-a-loop-in-python-tkinter)